# How can I use blockquote with \documentclass moderncv

Tags: moderncv, csquotes

I'm trying to use `\blockquote` (from the `csquotes` package) in a `moderncv` document, but the output does not look as it should (the quote is not indented and the string "csq@block" is prefixed to the quote).

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}   
\usepackage{csquotes}
\name{John}{Doe}
\begin{document}
\blockquote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
\end{document}
```

The output is this:
[image]

Is this an incompatibility between the two packages, and if so, which one is causing the problem? And is there a workaround for this?

Comment: No, I'm quoting from a student email praising my teaching ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The class `moderncv` doesn't define the `quote` and `quotation` environments, but rather a `quote` command taking an argument and this confuses `csquotes`.

Solution: load the `quoting` package and change the default environment used by `\blockquote`:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{quoting}
\SetBlockEnvironment{quoting}
\name{John}{Doe}
\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\blockquote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et
accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed
diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]